# Enable touch screen on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, gnome, virtualbox, touch-screen

I have CentOS 7 installed as a guest OS inside VirtualBox running in a Windows 8.1 host machine.  The host is a notebook computer with a touch screen.

The windows host can accept touch screen commands such as pushing submit buttons by pressing the screen, etc.  However, the CentOS 7 guest OS inside VirtualBox does not respond to touchscreen commands.  The CentOS 7 guest uses the gnome UI.

**How can I enable the touch screen in the CentOS 7 guest?**

Is it as simple as `yum install rhel-touch-screen-tools`?

Or do I need to change distros, do something to VirtualBox, choose a different UI to replace gnome, or some other specific thing that you can explain?

Comment: VitualBox has tickets about touch screens, therefore i assume it must support them (or, at least, some of them), you might need the correct guest additions though.  See the [X11 answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175825/how-to-setup-touch-screen-for-x11) about using `xinput` to find and enable your touch screen.

Comment: @grochmal  Does this mean that I should expect the touch-screen functionality to work out of the box with CentOS 7 as the host OS on another machine that also has a touch screen?  I have to develop a tablet app with Linux running on the tablet.  Therefore, the Linux version chosen will have to support touch screen.

Comment: Nope, it is just what that answer says: as with any piece of hardware, you might have the driver in the kernel or not.  On the other hand, i saw a lot of touchscreens working very well on linux machines recently.  There are several drivers in the kernel (most of them need `modprobe` on most distros though): `generic-libinput`, `elographics`, `magictouch`, `mutouch`, `palmax`; you must be rather unlucky to get a touchscreen that cannot be configured with one of these.  You also might need to configure the touch area in X11.

Comment: The other answer in your link seems not directly focused on RHEL or CentOS.  I was hoping for either `yum install something`, or at least something that diagnoses what is currently on the machine and then makes recommendations for the specific machine instead of treating it as generic `nix`.  In the past, the generic `nix` approaches to other problems have generally led to disasters.  Where can I find CentOS 7-specific instructions?